# What is the most performant way to construct ui in codename one?

Tags: user-interface, memory, garbage-collection, codenameone

In most of examples written by Codename One's authors the UI is made by code, like when you see code for Swing or Vaadin. But Codename One also has a UI Builder which allows to easy build and preview content before populating it.
I wonder if it would be better to build every window from scratch by code or just design it in the UI, and as its already loaded in memory it will be more efficient (mostly in memory weight) to set the new values and show new data on it. And that takes me to the question of how Codename one simulates the garbage collector process in every device hardware/software so we know that dereferencing data (Ex. set variables to null) will be good enough to get it out from memory.

Answer (score 1):

We are in the process of [releasing a new GUI builder](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/gui-builder-walkthru.html) (it's still alpha) which is why we don't have any new samples of the older GUI builder.

Samples don't work well for GUI builders as the GUI builder hides a lot of the logic and has a lot of generated code to make the sample feel either messy or incomplete.

However, GUI builders work rather well in videos (unlike coding) so you will notice that at least some of our videos use the old GUI builder.

Performance shouldn't be the reason to choose GUI builder or handcoding as performance is something you can tune in both cases.

Comment: Could the redundance of the generated code by the UI make it less straightforward than the handcrafted one, therefore a bit less performant?

Comment: Yes but keep in mind its code we generated and you might not be as proficient in Codename One as we are so it might balance out... Performance is a HUGE topic but the gist of it is the 80-20 rule. Most of the performance issues are in the big pieces and the GUI construction is a **tiny** piece. Theme is a HUGE performance issue since it applies in runtime.